# What does this comment in the EditText.java code mean?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I've looked through [EditText.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/EditText.java#109) , at line 109 ,  the comment below can be seen in the 
`getText()` method:

```
// This can only happen during construction.
```

What is its purpose?

Thanks

Comment: The purpose of a comment is to tell a programmer (human being) something.

Comment: text==null can happen only in constructor, it is not null once constructor finishes.

Comment: @AIMINPAN thks, would you tell me more when you say it is not null once constructor finishes?

Comment: @H.Riantsoa It means that after the constructor has finished executing, the text will *never* be null. If you don't understand the phrase "once constructor finishes" my recommendation is to head over to the Java official documentation, and read about Constructors; they are pretty important :) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html (in the URL's example, the variables initialized in the constructor of that `Bicycle` object, are _guaranteed_ to be assigned after the constructor finishes (when all the code in the ctor executed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will expand on Andreas' answer, tailored for this particular set of classes.

`EditText` is a subclass of `TextView`. That's why it's declared as:

`class EditText extends TextView` (Simplified…)

The EditText constructors, look like this:

```
public EditText(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}
public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.editTextStyle);
}
public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
}
public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}
```

Notice how each constructor calls the other until the last (long) one. 
That one is tricky, because it calls `super(…)` meaning it's now calling the super class' constructor (`TextView`).

EditText is then just a specialized TextView as we can infer from this; TextView also declares a variable called `text`, which EditText uses as well of course. When you ask an EditText for the `text`, it simply uses the code that the TextView already has and that you discovered:

```
@Override
public Editable getText() {
    CharSequence text = super.getText();
    // This can only happen during construction.
    if (text == null) {
        return null;
    }

    [rest of code removed for clarity]
}
```

So it asks its `super` (the TextView) for the `text`; why can this text be null? To answer that, you need to go look at the `TextView` itself (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java).

About 1000 lines of code later… the TextView declares its constructors; I'll paste one for simplicity but they are very simple:

```
public TextView(Context context) {
     this(context, null);
}
```

Notice they *again* call `this(…)` and *chain* the construction… one constructor calls the other and so forth… until the last big one for TextView is reached…

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public TextView(
        Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    // TextView is important by default, unless app developer overrode attribute.
    if (getImportantForAutofill() == IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_AUTO) {
        setImportantForAutofill(IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_YES);
    }
    setTextInternal("");
    [rest of code removed for clarity]
```

Notice something, this constructor, calls `setTextInternal("")`, that looks suspicious! it's setting the text to be an empty string upon construction, so it would be *impossible* for a `TextView` to have a null text after this constructor finishes (*you could use reflection… but let's not go there*); since `EditText` constructors are chained and end up *always* calling the `TextView` constructors, this method `setTextInternal("")` is **guaranteed to be called** at some point during the construction of the object in Java. (that's what Constructors are and that's a Java contract that would break 1/2 of the world if it were unreliable!).

What does this method do?

Apparently, a bunch of internal things, among other…

```
// Update mText and mPrecomputed
private void setTextInternal(@Nullable CharSequence text) {
    mText = text; // #### THIS IS WHERE IT SETS THE TEXT TO NON NULL ("").
    mSpannable = (text instanceof Spannable) ? (Spannable) text : null;
    mPrecomputed = (text instanceof PrecomputedText) ? (PrecomputedText) text : null;
}
```

If you remember that `EditText#getText()` called `super.getText()` guess what that looks like in super? (the `TextView`):

```
public CharSequence getText() {
    return mText;
}
```

That's right, the same `mText` reference/instance that `setTextInternal()` modified during the TextView construction.

That this is why *during construction* (and before `setTextInternal("")` is called, the field `mText` (that you access via `getText()`) can be null, but not after.

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

In all honesty, I don't even know why they do this and the comment seems kinda silly, but as you have probably already guessed, these classes are thousands of lines of code and one tends to believe *there must be a reason* for this to exist; the best you can do is start analyzing the entire TextView class. Good luck with that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the comment is to tell any programmer that thinks the next statement is redundant, i.e. that `text` can never be `null`, that they are wrong, because it *can* happen during construction of the `EditText` object, so don't remove the statement.